# APKファイルからIconを取得

Tags: android

APKファイルからiconを抽出する方法について
/sdcard/**.apk/res/drwable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png としてやるとこれは
ファイルではありませんと出てきました。
恐らく、zipfileのなかはFileとして扱うのは面倒だと思われます。

Comment: 試されたのはAPKファイルをZIPファイルとして参照してみた、という事でしょうか。

Comment: そうです。しかし、Fileではありませんとエラーが出たので別の方法を探すと下の答えの方法が出てきました

Answer (score 3):

**apktool**を使用することでapkファイルの展開(または再構築)を行う事ができます。
実行するにはJavaの環境が必要です。
https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

`> apktool d -s TARGET.apk -o OUTDIR`

Answer (score 0):

Androidアプリから取得する場合は

```
    String APKFilePath = "mnt/sdcard/myapkfile.apk";
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(APKFilePath, 0);
 pi.applicationInfo.sourceDir = APKFilePath;
 pi.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = APKFilePath;
 Drawable APKicon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);//icon
 String AppName = (String)pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);//アプリ名
```

APKiconはdraeableなのでDialogではsetIcon()として使えます